# Comic about 3rd reich after WWII

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

Some Years ago I discovered a comic someone posted on imgur.com.

It was about a Pilot of the German 3rd reich in a parallel universe, where the Nazis won the war.

It featured many of the experimental aircrafts, especially a non symmetrical plane, originally made by Bloom & Voss.

The pilot was very high decorated, I think with the highest medal possible.
The comic was completely collored.

I tried for some time to find it, but neither imgur itself nor google could help me.

Comment: This is pretty good detail, and provides uniquely identifiable details, but take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] and add any more details.

Comment: If it helps at all, the assymetrical bomber in the Luftwaffe was the BV-141.  Idea was to give the forward/aft visibility and gun coverage of a twin bomber, but with the simplicity and ease of pilot training of a single engine.  It wasn't a "Luftwaffe 1946" concept; it actually flew during the War, though it was late and not many were built.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the featured planes. I didn't know they were actually used. Thought there were only prototypes.

Answer (score 3):

How about [Hans Vogel is Dead](http://hansvogelisdead.tumblr.com/characters)?

[image: HANS JOACHIM KARL VOGEL]

> A Luftwaffe pilot, son of a Freikorps fighter, and graduate of the Hitler Youth, Hans Vogel is a mild-mannered young man of 22 whose apathetic views toward politics in the Third Reich has earned him a rather cushy career. He doesn’t ask any questions, and nobody comes looking for him late at night. When a bombing mission over England goes awry, however, Hans is shot down in flames and is killed immediately on impact.
>
> Unfortunately for him, that’s where his problems begin.

Comment: Unfortunately not. There was nothing undead or similar involved. Also the drawing style was different.  But this one sounds interesting, too. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You *might* be thinking of the comic book series ***Luftwaffe: 1946***, written and drawn by **Ted Nomura.** It began being published by Antarctic Press in 1996. A long, long time ago, I bought a secondhand copy of a trade paperback which I think collected the first few issues of the ***Luftwaffe: 1946*** series, although there were references in it which made it clear that it tied in with stuff which previously had been published in some other comic book series.

I did not find the writing captivating, and I've never bothered to look for a chance to buy any other stuff set in that alternate-history timeline. About the only things I clearly remember from it are:

1. Adolf Hitler was more successful in this timeline's version of WWII, and he came across as a fairly normal guy in what we saw of him. (I think the Holocaust never happened?) The one scene I really remember is one in which he is talking to a couple of kids (probably German kids) about their sketches for a possible comic book series they might like to publish someday, when they're older. I don't remember what sort of characters and setting it would have, but the implication was that Hitler was interested in their sketches, and maybe did a few sketches himself for them, because he was once a starving young artist in Vienna, and so he could relate to their ambitions in that area.
2. There was at least one attractive female fighter pilot working for the Luftwaffe. I don't remember exactly what she did in the plot, but she was definitely onstage.
3. There was a fair amount of talk about the technical side of things -- different planes which the Germans either did build in that era, or else might have if they'd gotten the chance.

I did some Googling just now, and here's a scanned image of a sample page which probably shows the same female pilot I was remembering (although I can't swear to it). If the art style seems to ring a bell in your memory, then we're probably talking about the same comic book series. (And if not, we probably aren't.)

[image]

P.S. I dug around and found [a brief online review](http://www.ourworlds.net/blackhawk/exclusives/rr-luft46.html) by someone whose memory of the series was a lot fresher than mine when he wrote it. Here's an excerpt from what he says:

> This is an alternate universe story in which Hermann Göring's death in
>   1918 and the 1937 discovery of a buried flying saucer allow Nazi
>   Germany to pour more resources into development of Wunderwaffen. The
>   Axis powers are more successful and the Allies less so, so the war
>   drags on. This comic book series (actually several mini-series and
>   special editions) is really a framework for Ted Nomura to draw highly
>   detailed pictures of hypothetical German aircraft as if they had gone
>   into operation. The depictions of aircraft, ships, tanks, etc., are
>   outstanding. His character work is strongly influenced by Japanese
>   manga and thus drifts away from the realism displayed in his vehicles.
>   The writing does not measure up to the artwork.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps possible you're thinking of *Twilight X* by Joseph Wight, published by Antarctic Press.  It's not, strictly speaking, about the Nazis winning the war, but rather about Neo-Nazis in a post-World War 3 future.  But it does get very detailed in terms of aircraft and such.  An example:

https://antarctic-press.myshopify.com/products/twilight-x-pm-vol-1

This is likely a fairly long shot, but it seemed worth mentioning.